# Limit of function $f(x) = \sqrt{(xa + d)^2 + x^2 b^2} - \sqrt{(xa - d)^2 + x^2 b^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> I tried to calculate limit when $x$ goes to infinity for the following function 
>   $$f(x) = \sqrt{(xa + d)^2 + x^2 b^2} - \sqrt{(xa - d)^2 + x^2 b^2}$$
>   where $a$, $b$, $d$  are some positive constants.

It's easy to see that terms before and after minus sign goes to infinity so that gives me indeterminate symbol. Is there some way to solve this problem?

Comment: What methods are you allowed to use?

Comment: You could multiply by $ \sqrt{(xa + d)^2 + x^2 b^2} + \sqrt{(xa - d)^2 + x^2 b^2} /  \sqrt{(xa + d)^2 + x^2 b^2} +  \sqrt{(xa - d)^2 + x^2 b^2} $

Comment: @YuriyS Any methoh, this is my private investigation out of curiosity -- not a homework.

Comment: @Milan What would that give me?

Comment: @Trismegistos You could try it and find out for yourself what it gives you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by $\sqrt{\cdot} + \sqrt{\cdot}$ at numerator and denomitor your get

$$\begin{aligned}f(x)&= \frac{4adx}{{\sqrt{(xa + d)^2 + x^2 b^2} + \sqrt{(xa - d)^2 + x^2 b^2}}}\\
\end{aligned}$$

And therefore $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)  = \frac{2ad}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ by pulling $x$ at the denominator as

$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{(xa + d)^2 + x^2 b^2} + \sqrt{(xa - d)^2 + x^2 b^2}&=x\left(\sqrt{(a+ d/x)^2 + b^2} + \sqrt{(a - d/x)^2 + b^2}\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$ for $x>0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} d/x =0$.

Easy then to get $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ as $f$ is odd.

Comment: I don't understand how you get such simple form in denominator I tried to work it out but I got $\sqrt{x^2 a^2 + 2xad + d^2 + x^2 b^2} - \sqrt{x^2 a^2 - 2xad + d^2 + x^2 b^2}$ I can pull $x^{-2}$ into square root but because of 2xad term I'm still left with $x^{-1}$ under square root.

Comment: I added some intermediate steps.

Comment: Thank you. Multiplying by conjugate was good trick. I wonder how did you come up with such trick.

Comment: Classical when you have a sum or difference of square roots.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably the one in mathcounterexamples.net's answer.

But that's just an algebraic trick. You can also give a solution using calculus:

> > If $0<s<t$ there exists $\xi\in(s,t)$ such that $\sqrt t-\sqrt s=\frac{t-s}{2\sqrt\xi}$.

Proof: Apply the Mean Value Theorem to the function $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Now let $t = (xa+d)^2+x^2b^2$ and $s=(xa-d)^2+x^2b^2$ and see what happens...

(One reason to do this is that this method can be applied in other situations where the algebraic trick is not available. MVT is the source of all wisdom.)

**Details added in response to a comment:** Let's say $a$, $x$ annd $d$ are positive, so if we  define $s$ and $t$ as above we have $s<t$. Now $s<\xi<t$ leads to $$\frac{t-s}{2\sqrt  t}<\frac{t-s}{2\sqrt \xi}<\frac{t-s}{2\sqrt s},$$or in other words $$\frac{2xad}{\sqrt{(xa+d)^2+x^2b^2}}<\frac{t-s}{2\sqrt\xi}<\frac{2xad}{\sqrt{(xa-d)^2+x^2b^2}},$$or$$\frac{2ad}{\sqrt{(a+d/x)^2+b^2}}<\frac{t-s}{2\sqrt\xi}<\frac{2ad}{\sqrt{(a-d/x)^2+b^2}}.$$Now let $x\to\infty$ and you're done.

(**Hehe:** When I posted this answer I hadn't worked out those details; it just seemed clear that  MVT "must" tell us what we need to know about $f(t)-f(s)$. Sure enough, MVT is the key to understanding the universe.)

### The Moral

Any time you need to figure out something about a quantity of the form $f(t)-f(s)$ (where $f$ is differentiable) you should always consider applying MVT. Because MVT *always* tells you *something* about $f(t)-f(s)$, and if $t-s$ is not too big that "something"  will often include everything there is to know about $f(t)-f(s)$. (Not going to give a precise definition of "not too big" here - work out what MVT tells you, and if that's what you needed to know then $t-s$ was not  too big...)

Comment: +1, because now I know about the source of all wisdom.

Comment: It's really nice, I have never seen MVT in this context :)

Comment: Using this method result is $2xad / \sqrt{\xi}$ which makes limit goes to infinity but my experiments with wolfram alpha shows that limit is finite. So I'm not sure about result...

Comment: @Trismegistos I don't know why you think $2xad/\sqrt\xi$ tends to infinity, but it's not  so. See revised version above...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It's true. Yesterday when I posted this answer I didn't know for a fact that the method would work, I simply believed it "must"
 work because MVT so  often tells us everything there is to know. Worked it out when the OP expressed skepticism, and sure enough. (See **The Moral** above...)

Comment: @Botond Which "context" might be relevant? In fact any time you want to figure out something about $f(t)-f(s)$ you should consider MVT - it always tells you something, and very often tells  you what you need to know.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that I didn't see the MVT being applied to these kind of limits, just the multiply by the conjugate method, so it was a big surprise for me :)

Comment: Now I see. You used squeeze theorem in conjunction with MVT. Since I already accepted different answer I will upvote your answer as valuable one.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\not=0$,
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{(xa \pm d)^2 + x^2 b^2} &=|x|\sqrt{\left(a \pm \frac{d}{x}\right)^2+ b^2}\\
&=|x|\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(1\pm\frac{2ad}{(a^2+b^2)x}+o(1/x)\right)^{1/2}\\
&=|x|\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(1\pm\frac{ad}{(a^2+b^2)x}+o(1/x)\right)\\
&=|x|\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\pm\frac{ad|x|/x}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+o(1)
\end{align}$$
where we used the expansion at $t=0$, $(1+t)^{1/2}=1+t/2+o(t)$.

Now it should be easy to verify that
$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x)  = \frac{2ad}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\quad\text{and}\quad \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x)  = -\frac{2ad}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=1/(2 d x)$. Then the limit of interest can be written as

$$\lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}\left(\sqrt{(2a d/t + d)^2 + b^2 d^2/t^2} - \sqrt{(2a d/t - d)^2 + b^2 d^2/t^2}\right)\\
\hspace{4cm}=2d\,\text{sgn}(t)\times \lim_{t\to 0^{\pm}}\frac{1}{t}\left[\sqrt{(a+t/2)^2+b^2}-\sqrt{(a-t/2)^2+b^2}\right].$$
The definition of the derivative therefore yields the limits for $t\to 0^{\pm}$ as

$$\pm 2d \frac{d}{dt}\left( \sqrt{(a+t)^2+b^2}\right)_{t=0}=\pm \frac{2ad}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$